# Merge polygons and plot using spplot()

Tags: r, r-maptools

I would like to merge some regions in gadm data and then plot the map. So far I have the following:

```
#install.packages("sp",dependencies=TRUE)
#install.packages("RColorBrewer",dependencies=TRUE)
#install.packages("maptools",dependencies=TRUE)
library(sp)
library(maptools)
#library(RColorBrewer)

# get spatial data
con <- url("http://gadm.org/data/rda/CZE_adm2.RData")
print(load(con))
close(con)

IDs <- gadm$ID_2
IDs[IDs %in% c(11500:11521)] <- "11500"
gadm_new <- unionSpatialPolygons(gadm, IDs)

# plot map
spplot(gadm_new, "NAME_2", col.regions=col, main="Test",colorkey = FALSE, lwd=.4, col="white")
```

However this results in error:

```
Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function "spplot", for signature "SpatialPolygons"
```

Now I have no idea what can possibly fix this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you're trying to do here.

The error is due to the fact that `spplot` is used to draw spatial objects with attributes, ie with associated data. Your `gadm` object is of class `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, so it defines polygons and associated data that can be accessed via the slot `gadm@data`. When you use `UnionSpatialPolygons`, you only get a `SpatialPolygons` class object, which can be plotted with `plot`, but not with `spplot` :

```
IDs <- gadm$ID_2
IDs[IDs %in% c(11500:11521)] <- "11500"
gadm_new <- unionSpatialPolygons(gadm, IDs)
plot(gadm_new)
```

[image]

If you want to use `spplot`, you have to merge your associated data manually, the same way you merged your polygons, and then build back a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`. One way to do it is the following :

```
gadm_new <- gadm
## Change IDs
gadm_new$ID_2[gadm_new$ID_2 %in% c(11500:11521)] <- "11500"
## Merge Polygons
gadm_new.sp <- unionSpatialPolygons(gadm_new, gadm_new$ID_2)
## Merge data
gadm_new.data <- unique(gadm_new@data[,c("ID_2", "ENGTYPE_2")])
## Rownames of the associated data frame must be the same as polygons IDs
rownames(gadm_new.data) <- gadm_new.data$ID_2
## Build the new SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
gadm_new <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(gadm_new.sp, gadm_new.data)
```

Then you can use `spplot` to plot a map with an associated attribute :

```
spplot(gadm_new, "ENGTYPE_2", main="Test", lwd=.4, col="white")
```

[image]

Note that here I only used the `ENGTYPE_2` variable of your data, not the `NAME_2` variable, as I don't see the point to represent a variable where each value seems unique for each polygon.

Comment: Thank you, this is the first time I'm trying to use R for such purpose and your answer is really great!